# How to make fish shell delete words like bash does

Tags: bash, key-bindings, fish

I'm giving a second try to the fish shell. One thing that really annoys me is the "new" behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> shortcut.

Consider following situation:

```
$ vim ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

...having the cursor at the end of the line.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, following happens:

- in bash: `~/.config/fish/config.fish` is deleted
- in fish: only `config.fish` is deleted

How can I make fish delete words that are separated by spaces only?

Comment: Im not familiar with fish shell, but this is often governed by a setting that defines what characters the line editor should consider a "word". e.g. in vim  you have the `iskeyword` option variable and zsh has the shell variable `$WORDCHARS` . i.e. by default the zsh line editor does the thing you want, but personally I want the `^W` to stop on file path segments, so I edited  `$WORDCHARS`. Sometimes the behaviour is specific to the line editor function you are calling too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"\cw" (in fish's notation) is bound to "backward-kill-path-component" (which `bind \cw` will tell you).

If you wish, you can bind it to something else, including input functions like "backward-kill-word" or any fish script - `bind \cw backward-kill-word` or `bind \cw "commandline -rt ''"` (which will remove the entire current token) or `bind \cw backward-kill-bigword`. See [the bind documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html) or `bind --help` for more information.

The difference between "word" and "bigword" here is that "word" will only go to the next non-word-character, which can be a "." or "/" or "-", among others, while "bigword" will truly go to the next whitespace character.

Note that the "bigword" functions have only been introduced in fish 2.3.0.

You can try these incantations in an interactive shell. If you decide to make it permanent, you'll need to add them to a function called `fish_user_key_bindings`.

Comment: Okay, this made me upgrade to 2.3 version, works well! Thanks!